# shared_timed_mutex not working the way i would expect

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mutex

for me, using g++, this breaks (hangs forever regardless of what time i put in chrono).   but on windows it works fine (sleeps for 1 second):

```
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::shared_timed_mutex mut;
    mut.lock();
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    mut.try_lock_shared_for(std::chrono::duration<double>(1));
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in undefined behavior land so all behavior is correct.  You are not allowed to try and lock the mutex in the thread that already owns (has locked) the mutex.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex/try_lock_shared_for):

> If `try_lock_shared_for` is called by a thread that already owns the mutex in any mode (shared or exclusive), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: yep, that's it, silly.   writing test cases for recurs/non-recursive is tricksy

Comment: @ErikAronesty If it helps C++ does have a recursive mutex and a timed recursive mutex but it doesn't have a shared version of either of those.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that recursive mutual exclusives should only be used, to fix old code, only if it is hard to refactor it. In general, recursive mutexes are sort of an indicator for bad design of concurrent code.

Comment: writing a lib, recurs support and even shared-recurs support is a requirement for some users.   everything works great now (hilok python lib)